# Symfony 2 Doctrine Oracle schema sync

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine, synchronization

I am new to symfony and doctrine and would appreciate some help ...

I am connecting doctrine to an oracle 11g database.

I have created an table/entity which contains nullable date fields.

The fields are described in YAML thus

```
    metar_time:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: METAR_TIME
    taf_time:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: TAF_TIME
    ltaf_time:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: LTAF_TIME
    storage_date:
        type: date
        nullable: true
        column: STORAGE_DATE
```

The database schema reflects the status of the fields as nullable dates with a default value of null.

The issue that I am having is that I can not get doctrine to recognise that the database and meta description are in sync.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE MET MODIFY (LTAF_TIME  DATE DEFAULT NULL, METAR_TIME  DATE DEFAULT NULL, STORAGE_DATE  DATE DEFAULT NULL, TAF_TIME  DATE DEFAULT NULL);


php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "1" queries were executed
```

Yet if I run the sql dump again the update is still outstanding.

I have cleared all the caches to rule that out as an issue.

Any suggestions welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue. Check [Incorrect type mapping on Oracle Platform](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-434)

*Some ref:*

> The problem is that Oracle has a "DATE" type, which is actually a DATETIME. That is why we map it to Doctrine's Datetime type.
>
> As a workaround, you can set this information yourself using:
> $conn->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('date', 'date');
> Be aware this is a global change for all columns. If you map DateTimes to a TIMESTAMP field you are good to go though.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response,  this answered my question ... I have found a similar issue with changing a column from not nullable to nullable.  The code generated by doctrine sets the default value to null but does not change the nullable status of the column.

`ALTER TABLE MET MODIFY (METAR  VARCHAR2(2000) DEFAULT NULL)`